# How to prove the combinatorial equality?

Tags: co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, convolution

Please, help me to understand following convolution (or give a reference):
$$
\sum_{R=0}^N \binom{R}{r} \binom{N-R}{n-r} = \binom{N+1}{n+1} 
$$
Why is it true?

Thank you!

Comment: Dear @ilya.gromov: the formula you gave is not a sentence, hence not even meaningful. I am confident you will get kind help at https://math.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: your lhs depends on $r$ while the rhs does not

Comment: Probably you want an extra $\sum_{r = 0}^R$ in there.

Comment: @LSpice With that extra sum the equality does not hold (neither with sum up to $n$)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე, right, sorry, I should have said to *replace* $\sum_{R = 0}^N$ by $\sum_{r = 0}^R$, in which case I think that it is correct (and the apparent dependence of the LHS on $R$ is illusory).

Comment: Oh, but then we have to change the RHS to $\binom N n$, and ensure that $R \le n$, so maybe that's too many changes to be what the OP intended.  In its modified form, this is [Vandermonde's convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity).

Comment: @LSpice, in that case it would be Vandermonde convolution. It's not what I'm looking for. The exprassion I wrote I found in "Probability Theory. The Logic of Science" of Jaynes on page 153.

Comment: Well, sure enough, that's just what Jaynes says.  [Google Books link](https://books.google.com/books?id=tTN4HuUNXjgC&pg=PA153).

Comment: Oh I see sorry - I was checking on Mathematica and it seems to have unusual convention with some $\binom pq$ with negative $q$ nonzero...

Comment: Simply putting the formula [into Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Csum_%7BR%3D0%7D%5EN%20%5Cbinom%7BR%7D%7Br%7D%20%5Cbinom%7BN-R%7D%7Bn-r%7D%20%3D%20%5Cbinom%7BN%2B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%24&p=1) returns some posts on math.SE which seem relevant - at least at the first glance - this one seems the closest: [Two identities with binomial coefficients](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354150).

Comment: This is really a question for [Math Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions).

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $r \le n$.  Then it seems to me that you could proceed as follows:  regarding integers as sets (and binomial coefficients as sets of sets, and sums of integers as disjoint unions of sets) in a hopefully obvious way, map $\sum_{R = 0}^N \binom R r\binom{N - R}{n - r}$ to $\binom{N + 1}{n + 1}$ by sending the element $A \times B$ of the $R$th summand to $A \cup \{R + 1\} \cup \{b + R + 2 : b \in B\}$.  The inverse map $\binom{N + 1}{n + 1} \to \sum_{R = 0}^N \binom R r\binom{N - R}{n - r}$ sends $\{i_1, \dots, i_r, i_{r + 1}, i_{r + 2}, \dotsc, i_n\}$ to $\{i_1, \dotsc, i_r\} \times \{i_{r + 2}, \dotsc, i_n\}$, viewed as an element of $\binom{\{1, \dotsc, i_{r + 2} - 1\}}r \times \binom{\{i_{r + 2} + 1, \dotsc, N\}}{n - r}$.

EDIT:  After following [@MartinSleziak](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/295022/how-to-prove-the-combinatorial-equality/295033#comment732441_295022)'s [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/354150), I think that this is just [Brian M. Scott's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/354158).  I leave it here in case it is an acceptable answer to the question, but mark it community wiki to avoid reputation.